# Best practices drawing onto a very large graphics context

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I need to draw onto a very, very wide context (possibly going into the 100,000's of pixels in width)

The stuff that I am drawing is simple (exclusively lines, ellipses and arcs).

Currently, I am using a tiling mechanism to render pieces of this image as SVG graphics in UIWebViews sitting in a UIScrollView. Horrible, I know. Performance is so bad it makes me want to hurt myself.

So I'm left with no choice but to draw things directly in Quartz. The problem is that I couldn't find any good information on handling such a large drawing.

The commands will be stored in a array (i.e [0] - line from x1,x2 to y1,2 [2] - arc at x1,x2,h,v etc...) which makes it possible to immediately determine what needs to be drawn at any point of time.

How should I best go about handling the actual drawing? Make a ginormous context then draw onto it, erasing the parts that go off screen? Can I draw straight into the UIScrollView?

Or am I supposed to performing some sort of tiling? Creating smaller views and drawing on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). It supports huge dimensions, yet only draws "tiles" that are visible. This means that in your `drawLayer:inContext:` you need to calculate how to draw the tile you were asked to draw. That might be quite complicated to implement but the performance boost makes up for this. I use this to draw a "strip" that is often over 20.000 pixels wide, tiled into 256 pixel pieces (this is the default).

You not only want this because of speed but also due to memory: if you really had a view or layer that were that big it would take up immense amounts of memory. Tiling is the only solution here.

See [this nice article by Michael Heyeck](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1857) on how to use CATiledLayer (Apple has a demo as well, but I think the linked article is better).

Comment: Great! This sounds like exactly that I need.

Answer (score 0):

If the stuff you are drawing is not static then using CATiledLayer(s) doesn't work very well.  A better solution is presented partly in http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1342 .  I've used this as a basis from some interactive drawing.  A little slow but I'm still optimizing.  Use http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/catiledlayer-how-to-use-it-how-it-works-what-it-does/ as a check list of whether you should use CATiledLayer(s) or not.